# EJS template for express.js app: transferring data into variable

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ejs

I want to transfer data from my node.js (express) app to a variable in the `<script>` on the page.

On the server-side I have

```
let tmp = JSON.stringify(await f(i));
console.log(tmp); //correct data [{"id":"729199920929701988","a ...}]
res.render('r.ejs', {"guilds": tmp});
```

Then in `r.ejs` I have

```
<input type='hidden' id='getter' value="<%= guilds %>">
<script>
    console.log(document.getElementById("getter").value); //correct value: [{"id":"729199920929701988","...}]
    let v = "<%= guilds %>";
    console.log(v);
    console.log("<%= guilds %>"); //dumb value with " changed to special symbols: [{&#34;id&#34;:&#34;729199920929701988&#34;,&#34...}]
</script>
```

The way with making an extra tag does not look like a good way in terms of performance. At least it makes the browser create one more element which takes time, especially if more than one element like this will be needed.

I would like to get the data directly in the `<script>` tag. There should be a way to avoid changing `"` to `&#34` when getting the value directly in the `<script>` tag (in fact, I do not understand why does that even happen). Can anyone help with that?

Comment: "The way with making an extra tag does not look like a good way in terms of performance." — See https://wiki.c2.com/?PrematureOptimization

Comment: I do not know how it works when passing directly into a variable in `<script>` but I have tested the way with an extra element, and it seemed like it has taken much time to process. A bare page loaded noticeably faster then the page that got data using ejs, so I implied that extra element did make the performance worse.

Comment: So you switched from a static page to a page which has to be generated with JavaScript, run a bunch of server side code, and sent the result (which will almost certainly have different caching rules because it is now generated instead of being static) and having changed all of those features, you assume that it is the extra input element that is the cause of the speed difference?

Comment: Well, maybe you are right but I would still like to know how to pass data directly into `<script>`, just for interest.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `let v = <%- guilds %>;` instead of `let v ="<%= guilds %>";` to tell ejs you need unescaped data

Comment: Now I get an error (client-side): `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier` in the line `let v = "<%- guilds %>";`

Comment: That's what happens when you put unescaped quotes inside a string literal delimited with quotes.

Comment: you don't need quotes: just `let v = <%- guilds %>;`. Updated the answer